# Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I've added a named second route but something seems to be going wrong when I try to navigate to a certain page.

Here's what my route looks like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId', component: ProjectDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/routes', component: RoutesComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/rides/new', component: AddRideComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/routes/:id', component: RideDetailsComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/stops', component: StopsComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/stops/new', component: AddStopComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId/stops/:id', component: StopDetailsComponent, outlet: 'project' },
  { path: 'drivers', component: DriversComponent },
  { path: 'drivers/new', component: AddDriverComponent },
  { path: 'drivers/:id', component: DriverDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];
```

This is what my named `router-outlet` looks like:

```
<router-outlet name="project"></router-outlet>
```

This is what my `routerLink` looks like:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { project: ['projects', projectId, 'routes'] } }]">Routes</a>
```

When I hover over the link it shows that the url is `http://localhost:4200/projects/99979de9-264c-278f-d7b4-6dec9a830974/(project:projects/99979de9-264c-278f-d7b4-6dec9a830974/routes)`

When I click on the link I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'projects/99979de9-264c-278f-d7b4-6dec9a830974'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'projects/99979de9-264c-278f-d7b4-6dec9a830974'
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1342)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.es5.js:1317)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you found solution for this?

Comment: @PraveenRawat, take a look at the answer below

Comment: here i am trying something like you but without any child routes. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156139/angular-2-4-routing- with-named-outlet). Can you look into this and tell me what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have not mentioned component for children component. Doing it like this solved it:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path: 'projects/:projectId', component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'routes', component: RoutesComponent, outlet: 'project' },
      { path: 'rides/new', component: AddRideComponent, outlet: 'project' },
      { path: 'routes/:id', component: RideDetailsComponent, outlet: 'project' },
      { path: 'stops', component: StopsComponent, outlet: 'project' },
      { path: 'stops/new', component: AddStopComponent, outlet: 'project' },
      { path: 'stops/:id', component: StopDetailsComponent, outlet: 'project' }
    ]
  }
];
```

and your router-outlet should be in ProjectDetailsComponent

```
<router-outlet name="project"></router-outlet>
```