# angular 2/4 routing with named outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to do implement named outlet in my app.

Here is my route config:

```
    {
    path: 'contact',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: ContactComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'list', component: ContactlistComponent },
      { path: 'hold', component: ContactOperationComponent, outlet: 'popup' }      
    ]
  }
```

Here is Outlet which i have kept in `AppComponent` with main `router-outlet`

```
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

And here is my routerLink which is calling my `Component`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/contact',{outlets:{popup:['hold']}}]">Hold</a>
```

But, the URL is generated by this approach is a mess. Here it looks like this:

```
/contact/(list//popup:hold)
```

It should be like this

```
/contact/list(popup:hold)
```

and due to that i can't even access passed parameters to called `Component`.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: actually this is correct, this is how its supposed to be....check this post http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/

Comment: as list and popup both are child routes, and you can definitely pass params to your named outlet, check the above mentioned post, I;m sure you will be able to resolve your issue

Comment: @JayDeeEss thanks for the quick reply in my actual post i found answer.

Comment: @PraveenRawat Can you describe your solution so that this question can be helpful to others?