# angular 2 passing parameters to named router-outlet?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I am sending parameters through named router-outlet to my `ChildComponent`. But in child component when i try to access params they are undefined.

Here is the route-config file

```
{ path: 'contact-hold/:id', component: OperationComponent, outlet: 'popup' }
```

Here is my link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['\',{outlets:{popup:['hold',1]}}]">Hold</a>
```

Here is what is looks like in browser:

```
/contact-list(popup:contact-hold/1)
```

And here is my router-outlet which i have kept in `AppComponent`:

```
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

I am accessing this param like this in my Operation Component:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=> {      
      console.log(params["id"]);
    })
```

I have gone trough other questions in stackoverflow and implemented the solution but still it's not working. What might be wrong with this code?

Comment: how are you accessing params in your Operation component. Also please post code for your router config as this route 'contact-hold/:id' should be defined under contact-list as children

Comment: @JayDeeEss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156139/angular-2-4-routing-with-named-outlet) i already had problem with such children route approach. Also i have updated my Operation Component part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

routeSub: any;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    console.log('params', params);
})
```